# Android email client and mail notifications

Tags: android, notifications, email-client

I compose an email with read notifications. One of the recipients uses Android 7 standard email client.

In emails I add this headers:

- Reply-To: `email2@domain.com`
- Disposition-Notification-To: `email2@domain.com`
- Read-Receipt-To: `email2@domain.com`
- Return-Receipt-Requested: `email2@domain.com`
- X-Confirm-Reading-To: `email2@domain.com`
- Generate-Delivery-Report: `email2@domain.com`

But send emails from another address: `email1@domain.com`

And only for that recipient I get notification on `email1@domain.com`. For example, from Outlook users I get notifications on `email2@domain.com` as I expect.

Additional: recipients, sender, and notification email addresses belong to the google domain.

What headers should I use to get notifications on `email2@domain.com` from different email clients? Is it possible?

I know some email clients may not send notification or send after get permission from users.